# Recording multiple songs that share channel settings and characteristics

Tags: cubase, project

I'm planning to record a few songs using Cubase 7.5 Artist. The arrangement for those is typically "rock", so several guitars, bass, synthies, and drums.

All of the songs are a little different. For example, I may use different amps for guitar tracks, or have some special effect tracks. That's why one guitar channel strip is not necessarily the exact same for another song. However, I'd like to have instruments like bass and drums sound the same across all songs.

Since I have so many different arrangements and different tempos, I started creating separate Cubase projects for each song. This makes it easier to play with the channel strips and use tempo maps, et cetera. It also prevents my number of tracks from growing fast.

But now that bass and drum recordings are coming into play, I'm naturally starting to mix the songs a little, and I find myself creating some semi-complex drum channel strips with EQs, compression and send effects. Those sound nice, but now I have a problem: **how do I get my channel settings to all the other songs?**

Put differently, how do I sync some specific track settings?

I don't necessarily want to save each insert effect on every channel to a preset, then have to open every other song, and load that preset. Even *Track Presets* would mean going back and forth, re-loading the presets.

I've been to several professional studios where each song was handled as a separate project, but here, not much mixing was needed due to the overall production quality (i.e. less EQing needed, good "out of the box" sound, etc).

Answer (score 2):

Without going heavily into detail, 3 possible ways to approach it…

- try setting up a default project with the things you use the most, from scratch.
- go back through your previous projects, save track presets, then import those to your default.
- open an old project with a lot of re-usable data, trash all the instrumentation & mixes & save that [as a copy, of course] to be a new default.

Personally, I find whenever I go to all the trouble of saving out some really, really useful defaults, I almost never need them again in quite the same way.
Only thing I end up re-using is my mastering chain, everything else I make on the fly.

Comment: That works really well if I have a preset that I *know* works, and if I want to start recording fast, but for example, I've never mixed a lot of bass before, so I don't have a reference. I'll use some default for recording, and then during mixing, I'll find other settings I may want to use for all 10+ other songs (e.g. so that the low frequencies are not too much). How do I get that to the other projects without having to open up 10 of them and load each preset into the bass track? (The same goes of course for kick, snare, hi-hat, overheads, toms, etc.)

Comment: Would have to be presets, I guess - you can save insert, EQ & channel strip FX chains separately; then it's just down to good cataloguing for media bay.

Comment: Btw, I'm not too sure, based on your question - but you know presets don't 'live' in the project, they become global once saved.

Answer (score 1):

In Cubase, you can save the channel strip settings by selecting a channel, then look for the drop down menu at the upper right of the Mix Console. Then 'Save/Load Selected Channels'. 
Just make sure you have a channel selected or it won't show.

Edit: Doing this will save the entire channel strip, rather than going with the track preset option.